# Stucked at one regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match everything (backward) from "*" ...baaack... and immediately when first ")" will be find stop.

Example:

```
teeeext)
text))))
from next line start selecting because this is last ")")

SELECT
SELECT
SELECT
*** // stop selecting
```

I came with this expression:

```
(?<=\)).+\*
```

But this selects everything from first ")" until *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match everything from the last `)` character to the first `*` character use this pattern:

```
(?<=\))[^)*]+\*
```

The `[^)*]` means any character *except* `)` or `*`. But this will include the first `*` in the match. If you'd like to have it not to include the `*`, use a look-ahead:

```
(?<=\))[^)*]+(?=\*)
```

Alternatively, if you are willing to make a bit of change to your code, you can just use a group:

```
\)([^)*]+)\*
```

But you'll have to do a little more work to extract this group from the match.

Comment: This one" (?<=\))[^)*]+(?=\*) works like a charm... i was close enough  in one of my tries there were group except [^)] but it did not work .. and your code work only if there is this "(?=\*)" at the end of expression. Could you please explain to me somehow better ? I understand all symbols but hmmm

Comment: @Trki: I've posted a comparable regex to this one, and full explanation of how it works, the `(?=*)` is explained there, I think

Comment: `(?=\*)` means 'must be followed by a `*`'. See the documentation about regex [assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Comment: yea i just read it :) Ok thx guys @EliasVanOotegem for answers! His expression selects even the sentence with *** so i will use your expression and his teory :)

Comment: @Trki: Of course, for your requirements, this is the regex I'd use, too. I wasn't clear on what the match's delimiter should be (`***` or a single `*`). If you don't mind, though, upvoting my answer? I did put in the effort of explaining it all, and I'd quite like to see my effort rewarded :-P

Comment: i upvoted it before i read this comment :) (check times if you can :D ) I had problem complete my expression myself because i always tried to read it backwards and i always tried something like (with lookbehind) [^*] But this matchs everything except * and when i type: [^)*] it means everything except ) and * and the missing bracets do the job with combination of lookbehind.. this trick i missed :) thx guys once again.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand this question properly. You want to match everything that follows *the last* closing parentheses (`)`), and preceeds `***`.
The expression you're looking for, I think is this:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\))[^)]+(?=\*{3})/m',$text, $matches);
```

Which, when applied to your example string returns:

```
array (
    0 => '

      SELECT
      SELECT
      SELECT
      ',
)
```

How it works:

- `(?<=\))`: a positive lookbehind. The rest of the expression can only match, if it was preceeded by `)`
- `[^)]+`: Matches everything but `)`, this is to make sure the lookbehind references the last closing `)`
  There's no need for you to include `*` in the non-matching chars. If the delimiter is three asterisk chars, even so, if to be sure, you can make this pattern non-greedy: `[^\)]+?`. If the end-delimiter might be a single asterisk, you should include the `*` in this class (`[)*]+`).
- `(?=\*{3})`: positive lookahead. The preceding (`[\)]+`) can only be matched provided it is followed by `***`
  If a single `*` is enough to delimit the section you wish to match, change the regex to `/(?=\))[^)]+(?=\*)/`.
- `m`: the multi-line modifier, because your example is a multiline string, it could come in useful

The matches of the lookaround assertions are zero-width, and will not be part of the match. Job done.
The main *"trick"* is that the chars that you have to use in your lookarounds are special chars in a regular expression, and need to be escaped, hence `\*` and `\)` instead of just simple `*` and `)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
[^)*]+(?=\*)
```

Meaning : greedily take every non-')' and non-'*' character until a * is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
\)([^(\))])*$
```

This one works for me.